# Second generation Managed Package - ConnectedApp isAdminApproved and permissionSetName

Tags: connected-apps, permission-sets, 2gp, postinstall

For our second generation managed package, I hoped to pre-configure the **ConnectedApp** like this so our Permission Set is associated:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ConnectedApp xmlns="https://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <version>1.0</version>
  <developerName>samp__MyConnectedApp</developerName>
  <label>My Connector</label>
  <description>Allows users to use the My Connector Connected App</description>

  <logoUrl>https://www.example.com/logo.png</logoUrl>
  <infoUrl>https://www.example.com</infoUrl>
  <contactEmail>support@example.com</contactEmail>

  <canvasConfig>
    <accessMethod>Post</accessMethod>
    <canvasUrl>https://api.example.com</canvasUrl>
    <lifecycleClass>MyCanvasLifecycle</lifecycleClass>
    <locations>Visualforce</locations>
    <locations>Aura</locations>
    <locations>ServiceDesk</locations>
    <locations>PageLayout</locations>
    <samlInitiationMethod>None</samlInitiationMethod>
  </canvasConfig>

  <oauthConfig>
    <isAdminApproved>true</isAdminApproved>
  </oauthConfig>

  <permissionSetName>MyPermissionSet</permissionSetName>

</ConnectedApp>
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I believe this can't work because:

1. Salesforce only allows Managed Packages to install Connected Apps with the **OAuth Policy** / **Permitted Users** set to **All users may self-authorize** and it appears this step must be completed manually for security reasons.
2. Not sure if this is a factor but connected apps in 2GP rely on a previously published Connected App so some of the metadata is not present in the 2GP's ConnectedApp metadata.

I am trying to minimize to post-installation configuration for the System Administrator and am asking them to manually do these steps:

1. Setup / App Manager - Select **Manage** next to our Connected App, click **Edit Policies**, change the dropdown to **Admin approved users are pre-authorized**.
2. Clone the Permission Set that comes with our Managed Package then associate the clone with the Connected App and assign that one to users.

If I can get rid of the both steps that would be great. But I especially want to get rid of the second step because it's just awkward and hacky.

I considered even trying to call the Metadata API via Apex but there'd be even more setup steps to make that work.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.